# Qt Creator Session Manager Bug?

Tags: c++, qt, session, user-interface

The default session works as expected, but when creating a new session, neither the projects nor the editors are restored. The current projects and editors are closed after ‘switch to,’ but nothing is loaded and I am left with blank editor windows (laid out as they were before initiating the switch) and no projects loaded. Any suggestions on how to further debug or otherwise resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

(Using Qt Creator 3.2.2 on Windows 8.1)

(I also created a new session called ‘xxx’ and grepped for ‘xxx’ in my project directory as well as AppData/Roaming and AppData/Local and all subdirectories thereof, and did not find the string anywhere.)

Comment: Never had problems with switching sessions. A new session will always be empty. But if you close your session / IDE and open this session the next time, it will be restored.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.   I misunderstood the usage before.   I will post an answer that will hopefully help the next guy that runs into a similar misunderstanding.   Maybe the Qt documentation could be improved a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to successfully use sessions now.  I had previously expected “New” to create a new session with the current state, but I see now that it does not work that way.

If I understand correctly now, the current state is tracked by the currently open session, and saved on  switch. Therefore, when one switches to another session, the state of the GUI just before switching is available in the session from which one switched.

A new session is blank, so if a new session is created and then one switches to it, there will be nothing available, so no projects or editors will be loaded and the window arrangement will remain in the same layout as it was before switching (but with empty editors).

To create a new session with the current state, use clone.